# Android GCM registration id is empty for some devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hello everyone I am Using GCM in my android app. GCM Registration id is generated in some devices but in some devices it returns empty regId. what should i do?? Basically I am using Android hive example project in my app. When that example project is run all the devices get GCM regId but when i use this code snippet in my example some devices registered successfully but some devices returns regId empty.

Comment: How did you get `RegistrationId`?

Comment: simply on Registerd() method of GCMintentservice

Comment: Check for the play services on the phone.

Comment: But why same device returns regId on the sample example project of Android hive

Comment: It returns an empty regId when you call the `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);`? If so, your registration info might be lost in your server, you might want to register again with the GCM.

Comment: how to register again?? @ztan

Comment: You might want to check out the `RegisterActivity.java` section in this tutorial. http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/